# Form validation error not being raised in django

Tags: python, django

I cannot get my `Django` form to raise a `ValidationError` when I try to create a custom field validation. I can see the new hidden input field, but when I try to enter a value it doesn't seem to detect an error.

I also tried `def clean(self)` instead of `clean_honeypot()` and that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms

class SuggestionForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    suggestion = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    honeypot = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput, label="Leave Empty")

    def clean_honeypot(self):
        honeypot = self.cleaned_data['honeypot']
        if len(honeypot) > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Honeypot should be left empty. Bad bot!'
            )
        return cleaned_data
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms

def hello_world(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def suggestion_view(request):
    form = forms.SuggestionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.SuggestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send_mail(
                'Suggestion from {}'.format(form.cleaned_data['name']),
                form.cleaned_data['suggestion'],
                '{name} <{email}>'.format(**form.cleaned_data),
                ['leigh.christopher2@gmail.com'])
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                "Thanks for your suggestion")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('suggestion'))
    return render(request, 'suggestion_form.html', {'form': form})
```

**template:**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Suggest an idea!{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The method should `return honeypot`. Don't think that's what's making the validation fail though

Comment: When I add the 'validates' option I get an error 'self not defined'

Comment: @user6210879 Add `elif form.errors` and than a warning massage to test if errors are detected at all. Put this after `if form.is_valid`.